# не получаются вывести отрицательные значения на оси X

Tags: python, matplotlib

Вопрос по сути связан с восприятием, у меня не выходит отрисовать функцию в отрицательных значениях по оси Х (в диаппазоне от -1000 до 1000 ).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x2 = [i for i in range(-1000,1000)]
y2 = [(x2[i]**2) for i in range(len(x2))]

#y2 = [(x2[i]**2) for i in range(-1000, 1000)]

plt.plot(y2)

#plt.xlim(-1000, 1000)

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте ось Х в `plot()` тоже:

```
plt.plot(x2,y2)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]